# How does one bulk import contacts into exchange; some with duplicate proxy addresses?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, proxy, exchange-2013

We are trying to bulk import contacts with CSV as follows:

```
Import-Csv .\ExternalContacts.csv|%{New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName}
```

We get an error because some contacts have the same proxy addresses attribute. There are multiple doctors with the same address (ie: 5555555555@domain.com).

How would one fix this or work around it?

Answer (score 0):

> > We get an error because some contacts have the same proxy addresses attribute.

To find the mailboxes(**User Mailboxes, Resource Mailboxes, and Shared Mailboxes**), **Contacts/Users** and **Groups** which have the same proxy addresses(**55555@domain.com**), you could run the command 
" ***Get-Mailbox | where {$_.EmailAddresses -eq “<55555@domain.com>”}*** ", " ***Get-MailContact | where {$_.EmailAddresses -eq "<55555@domain.com>"}*** " and " ***Get-DistributionGroup | where {$_.EmailAddresses -eq "<55555@domain.com>"}*** ":
 [image]
 [image]
 [image]

If there is the same proxy address **55555@domain.com**, you could remove it by running the command(Such as **mailboxes**) " ***Set-Mailbox -Identity  -EmailAddresses @{remove="xxxxx@domain.com"}*** ", then you could continue to import contacts.